# Is there a way to acquire a lock in Redis? (Node.js)

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, node.js, redis

My Node.js application accepts connections from the outside. Each connection handler reads a SET on Redis, eventually modifies the set itself, then moves on. The problem is that in the meanwhile another async connection can try to read the same SET and try to update it or decide its next step based on what it reads.

I know that Redis does its best to be atomic, but this is not quite sufficient for my use case. Think about this: the set is read to understand if it's FULL (there is a business rule for that). If it's FULL, then something happens. The problem is that if there is one only slot left, two semi-concurrent connections could think each one is the last one. And I get an overflow.

I there a way to keep a connection "waiting" for the very short time the other eventually needs to update the set state?

I think this is a corner case, very very unluckely... but you know :)

Using another key as the "lock" is an option, or does it stink?

Comment: I don't wish to dup Salvatore's answer here as mine.  He's addressed this before.  Use SETNX and WATCH to simulate locks. https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for `WATCH` with `MULTI/EXEC`.  Here's the pattern that both threads follow:

```
WATCH sentinel_key
GET value_of_interest
if (value_of_interest = FULL)
    MULTI
    SET sentinel_key = foo
    EXEC
    if (EXEC returned 1, i.e. succeeded)
        do_something();
    else
        do_nothing();
else
    UNWATCH
```

The way this works is that all of the commands between `MULTI` and `EXEC` are queued up but not actually executed until `EXEC` is called.  When `EXEC` is called, before actually executing the queued instructions it checks to see if `sentinel_key` has changed at all since the `WATCH` was set; if it has, it returns `(nil)` and the queued commands are discarded.  Otherwise the commands are executed atomically as a block, and it returns the number of commands executed (1 in this case), letting you know you won the race and `do_something()` can be called.

It's conceptually similar to the `fork()/exec()` Unix system calls - the return value from fork() tells you which process you are (parent or child).  In this case it tells you whether you won the race or not.

Answer (score 4):

How about using [blpop](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) to do locking. `blpop key 5` to wait 5 seconds for `key`. At start put item(to identify queue is not empty) at key. The connection acquiring the lock should remove item from key. The next connect then can't acquire the lock, because empty, but blpop has the following nice property:

> Multiple clients can block for the same key. They are put into a
>   queue, so the first to be served will be the one that started to wait
>   earlier, in a first-BLPOP first-served fashion.

When connection which acquired lock has finished task it should put back item back in queue, then the next connection waiting can acquire lock(item).

Comment: Seems quite what I need. I've to check how it could perform in a Node.js process though. Upovote, at least :)

Comment: @Claudio so this the answer you were looking for, but you mark the other one as correct answer? :"D